# Timeout while deploying Java Application to remote glassfish server from Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, glassfish

while deploying to a remote Glassfish 4.1 Server from Netbeans 8.0.1, i get a Timeout.

I configured the Glassfish Server by adding a new Server Instance and that seemed to work. I can see the applications running on the server and i am able to undeploy a application (directly from netbeans).
But when i try to deploy my application to the remote Server, i get a timeout Exception.

(i used enable-secure-admin to gain remote access from netbeans to the server)

What confuses me is, that when i enabled secure admin, i expected to see a https:// url in netbeans. But this url starts with http:// and i cant find an option to change this.

Server Attributes:

```
Host: [remote-ip]
DAS Port: 4848
Domain: domain1 (same as on the remote server)
Target: empty
Username PW : as set on the remote server
```

> "Enable JDBC Driver Deployment" and "Preserve Sessions Across Redeployment" are checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please attach the logs.

most probably its issue with the grizzly jar.
Please try the patched grizzly jar and see if it works for you.

Checkout : https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1713 for the same

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The grizzly Version on the remote Server is 2.3.15. This issue was fixed in 2.3.16. So i think you are right but can't test it now. I'll be back when i tested it and give feedback.

Comment: You were right. Thank you for your help. I tried the same with glassfish 4.0 and it worked without problems. I only got problems finding a patched grizzly jar. Maybe you can tell me which way to go to find it.

Comment: I have also been unable to find "drop-in" replacement JARs for Grizzly and other libraries used by Glassfish.  Right now  I am trying to build them myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534503/updating-grizzly-in-glassfish-4-1